# Same statistics error while using gem5 driven Ramulator in full system simulation for x86

Tags: gem5

I am trying to run a script in gem5 full system simulation with Ramulator. I have a checkpoint simulation in order to not to boot every time that I have to simulate. The goal is to get debug traces from the simulation in order to inspect the efficiency of the script. When I simulate without Ramulator, it works great. However, when I add the arguments for Ramulator, I get the following error:

```
panic: same statistic name used twice! name=ramulator.active_cycles_0
Memory Usage: 10703888 KBytes
```

I looked around but couldn't find anything about this error. Here is my script:

```
# Initialize the common paths
source path_init.sh

# Path to the directories
config_py=$GEM5_CONFIGS/example/fs.py
outdir=$RESULTS/example_fs/Ramulator

# disk and binaries for the full system simulation
kernel=/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/scratch/system/binaries/vmlinux-4.14.134
image=/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/scratch/system/disks/linux-x86.img
ramulator_conf=/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/ext/ramulator/Ramulator/configs/DDR4-config.cfg

# Ramulator parameters
ramulator_config=$GEM5_REPOSITORY/ext/ramulator/Ramulator/configs/DDR4-config.cfg

# Flag parameters
touch=$outdir/exec_debug_ramulator_fs.txt

# checkpoint 
rcS_file=/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/scratch/default/ManCommand.rcS
chkpt_dir=$RESULTS/example_fs/Checkpoint/


mkdir -p $outdir
#--debug-flags=Exec \
    #--debug-file=$outdir/exec_debug_ramulator_fs.txt \
$GEM5 --debug-flags=Exec \
    --debug-file=$outdir/exec_debug_ramulator_fs.txt \
    -d $outdir $config_py $* \
    --cpu-type AtomicSimpleCPU \
    --caches \
    --l2cache \
    --mem-size 10GB \
    --mem-type=Ramulator \
    --ramulator-config=$ramulator_config \
    --disk-image $image \
    --kernel $kernel \
    --script $rcS_file \
    --checkpoint-dir $chkpt_dir \
    --checkpoint-restore=1 \
    --num-cpus 2 \
    > $outdir/cmd.txt \
    2> $outdir/cerr.txt

# Ramulator arguments to add:
#   --mem-type=Ramulator \
#   --ramulator-config=$ramulator_config \
```

and here is the full cerr.txt file:

```
warn: Physical memory size specified is 10GB which is greater than 3GB.  Twice the number of memory controllers would be created.
info: kernel located at: /home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/scratch/system/binaries/vmlinux-4.14.134
system.pc.com_1.device: Listening for connections on port 3456
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7001
panic: same statistic name used twice! name=ramulator.active_cycles_0
Memory Usage: 10703888 KBytes
Program aborted at tick 0
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z15print_backtracev+0x2c)[0x56040fb2eabc]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z12abortHandleri+0x4a)[0x56040fb40cca]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f35d2cc4890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7f35d1706e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7f35d1708801]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x74642f)[0x56040eb4d42f]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN5Stats4Info7setNameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x205)[0x56040fa8afa5]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN5Stats8DataWrapINS_6ScalarENS_15ScalarInfoProxyEE4nameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x1d)[0x56040ebe59dd]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9ramulator8StatBaseIN5Stats6ScalarEE4nameENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x61)[0x56040fceb7b9]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9ramulator4DRAMINS_4DDR4EE8regStatsERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0xbd)[0x56040fcc7c71]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9ramulator13MemoryFactoryINS_4DDR4EE15populate_memoryERKNS_6ConfigEPS1_ii+0x136)[0x56040fcbf511]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9ramulator13MemoryFactoryINS_4DDR4EE6createERKNS_6ConfigEi+0x28a)[0x56040fcbcead]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFPN9ramulator10MemoryBaseERKNS0_6ConfigEiEPS6_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS5_Oi+0x49)[0x56040fcc0883]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZNKSt8functionIFPN9ramulator10MemoryBaseERKNS0_6ConfigEiEEclES5_i+0x60)[0x56040fcbe774]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9ramulator11Gem5WrapperC2ERKNS_6ConfigEi+0x118)[0x56040fcba968]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9Ramulator4initEv+0x8d)[0x56040f854bbd]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x11e5d16)[0x56040f5ecd16]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x7674c4)[0x56040eb6e4c4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6ff3)[0x7f35d2f72763]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7d8)[0x7f35d30b0908]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5bf6)[0x7f35d2f71366]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7d8)[0x7f35d30b0908]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5bf6)[0x7f35d2f71366]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7d8)[0x7f35d30b0908]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x7f35d2f6b5d9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6ac0)[0x7f35d2f72230]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7d8)[0x7f35d30b0908]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5bf6)[0x7f35d2f71366]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7d8)[0x7f35d30b0908]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x7f35d2f6b5d9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_StringFlags+0x76)[0x7f35d301b6f6]
/home/tohumcu/Stage/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z6m5MainiPPc+0x63)[0x56040fb3f7d3]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your best bet is to open a ticket in their issue tracker. But this should be simple to fix by looking at their source. As the error says, a stat must be being redefined twice somewhere. I'd also have a look at how stats are defined, and then try to figure it out a bit.

Comment: @CiroSantilli I have just figured it out that my memory definition was too large. gem5 is creating a second memory when you want more than 3GB. Apparently, Ramulator can't work with two memory locations as it will have the same module name.

Answer (score 1):

When I check the cerr.txt of my checkpoint simulation, I saw that gem5 was creating two memory modules in config.ini and thus creating the problem for Ramulator. This is due to gem5s behaviour of creating another memory module after 3G. Ramulator is not capable of working with more than 1 module. When I fixed my memory size to the max limit of 3GB and re-creating a checkpoint, I had no more issues.